# To select only AutoCAD Plant 3D object properties and deselect non-AutoCAD

Tags: c#, autocad

I am seeking assistance with retrieving all the properties of an object in AutoCAD Plan 3D without selecting other objects in AutoCAD, such as lines, blocks, or text. You can review my code. While debugging and selecting an AutoCAD Plan 3D object individually, it works fine. However, when I select an object that includes both AutoCAD and AutoCAD Plan 3D components, an error occurs, as illustrated in the image below.

So someone can help me repair it (only select AutoCAD plan 3D object)

Thanks !

```
public void GetPipingProperties()
 {
    
     Editor ed = AcadApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
     PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
     opts.MessageForAdding = "Select objects to obtain properties: ";
     PromptSelectionResult selRes = ed.GetSelection(opts);
     if (selRes.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
     {
         PlantProject currentProj = PlantApplication.CurrentProject;
         PipingProject pipingProj = (PipingProject)currentProj.ProjectParts["Piping"];
         DataLinksManager dlm = pipingProj.DataLinksManager;
         foreach (ObjectId objectId in selRes.Value.GetObjectIds())
         {
             int rowId = dlm.FindAcPpRowId(objectId);
             List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> properties;
             properties = dlm.GetAllProperties(rowId, true);
             ed.WriteMessage($"\nProperties for object {objectId}:");
             for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
             {
                 ed.WriteMessage($"\nProperty name: {properties[i].Key} = {properties[i].Value}");
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
        
         ed.WriteMessage("\nSelection canceled or error occurred.");
     }
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaI4r.png)

Comment: I haven't worked with ACad since a large AutoLisp project in 1989. But, looking at your code and the exception, I'm guessing that of the objects you are looping through in th `foreach`, at least one has no links. Does the data links manager have a call to test if an object has links? What do you see when you debug this? In the worst case, catch that exception and ignore the failing object(s)

Comment: I Have attach image for my debug. You can see my this problem. @Flydog57

Comment: Yes, i saw that. It was the source of my comment. Does the exception happen the first time through the loop or a subsequent pass. If you catch (and throw away) the exception, dies your code work for some objects? Does the data links manager provide a call that would allow you to skip problematic objects?  It's very hard to debug this from here

Comment: I don't know many SDK in AUTOCAD PLAN 3D. It maybe hard code with newbie for me. with only AUTOCAD. It have many document for that, however with AUTOCAD PLAN 3D there is very little document